# Backtrace of "git clone" running inside qemu-user-emulation based arm-chroot

Tags: chroot, dpkg, qemu, gdb, multiarch

I'm running a wheezy:armhf chroot using [qemu user emulation](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation#Appendix:_chrooting_into_target_file_systems) on my jessie:x86_64 system. Somehow, a `git clone` on a particular private repository will hang inside the chroot, while succeed natively. This might be a bug, who knows? To improve my karma, I want to find out what's going on!

As a side-note: the hang I'm experiencing is occurring with git-2.0 inside jessie:armel chroot as well... The hang does not occur inside a full-system-emulation. So I went on digging in the *wheezy:armhf* rabbithole, just because I had to choose one... I cannot test on a native machine...

So. There is no `git-dbg` packet, I roll my own. Inside the wheezy:armhf chroot:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot
sudo apt-get build-dep git
apt-get source git && cd git-1.7.10.4
DEB_CFLAGS_APPEND="-fno-stack-protector" DEB_CXXFLAGS_APPEND="-fno-stack-protector" DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS=hardening=-stackprotector,-fortify DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="noopt nostrip nocheck" fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -j´getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN`
sudo dpkg -i ../git_1.7.10.4-1+wheezy1_armhf.deb
```

As far as I read the [gcc-documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fstack-protector-990), setting `DEB_CFLAGS_APPEND` and `DEB_CXXFLAGS_APPEND` additionally with `-fno-stack-protector` is not needed, but anyhow, want to be sure)

Then, using qemu's builtin [gdb_stub](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2011-08/msg02092.html) inside the chroot I'm doing:

```
QEMU_GDB=1234 git clone /path/to/breaking/repo /tmp/bla
```

Debugging inside the qemu throws an *unsupported syscal 26* error.

Firing up `gdb-multiarch` outside the chroot, to connect:

```
gdb-multiarch -q
(gdb) set architecture arm                    # prevents "warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description"
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
(gdb) set sysroot /opt/chroots/wheezy:armhf
(gdb) file /opt/chroots/wheezy:armhf/usr/bin/git
Reading symbols from /opt/chroots/wheezy:armhf/usr/bin/git...done. # good! has debug symbols!
(gdb) list                                    # works! code is not stripped
(gdb) step
Cannot find bounds of current function        # meh...
(gdb) backtracke
#0  0xf67e0c90 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()                       # wtf?
```

Giving a `continue` to let the clone happen will result in a hang, sending a `ctrl-c`  is ignored.

Generating a core-file and loading it into gdb (inside the chroot) will give me a corrupt stack:

```
gdb -q /usr/bin/git qemu_git_20140514-160951_22373.core
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/git...done.
[New LWP 22373]
Cannot access memory at address 0xf67fe948
Cannot access memory at address 0xf67fe944
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf678b3e4 in ?? ()
#1  0xf678b3d4 in ?? ()
#2  0xf678b3d4 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Now I'm lost.

Where is the problem? Did I miss some detail in the qemu-user-emulation? Do I have to use a completely emulated arm-machine? A misunderstanding in cross-debugging? gdb-multiarch limitations? The creation of debug-packages?

Thanks for any suggestions, pointers, hints, tips, comments and what-not.

My best guess in the moment is based on the fact that `git` does a clone (I can see two processes/threads), but the `QEMU_GDB` environment variable is unset by qemu after using. Hence only the initial process is going to gdb. See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/proot_me/ev2rS7kma30) for example.

But still: I should be able to properly debug the parent process? I can easily cross-debug a hello-world MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this particular hang of "git clone" is a qemu-related problem... Other problems in the qemu-user-emulation prevail, so I have to fall back to full-system emulation... ;-(

Using a `qemu-user-static`, compiled from their git (the qemu-2.0.0+dfsg-4+b1 currently in jessie has less fixes and won't work for my case...):

```
git clone git://git.qemu-project.org/qemu.git $HOME/qemu.git && cd $HOME/qemu.git
./configure --static --disable-system --target-list=arm-linux-user --prefix=$HOME/qemu.install --disable-libssh2
make && make install
sudo cp $HOME/qemu.install/bin/qemu-arm /opt/chroots/wheezy:armhf/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
```

so...

However, I'm still not able to get backtrace of complex programs...

Comment: Please can you fill a bug report http://wiki.qemu.org/Contribute/ReportABug. You are competent and you're describing the problem very well.

Comment: Hey, I tried compiling latest git and I also have this problem, it only manifest itself when using smart http, dumb http works fine. Did you have any progress?